# Can a non-enumerated device conduct DMA operations?

Tags: fpga, bus, pcie

PCIe devices can read or write to memory, i.e. can do DMA without requiring a device driver. For example: pcileech (The PCIe FPGA device is controlled by another computer). If I remember correctly, if you flash a device's firmware (let's say an FPGA device) and input 0xFFFF as device and vendor ID, the device won't be enumerated by BIOS. I am wondering, if a PCIe device can conduct DMA operations (memory read and write) by bus mastering even when it is not enumerated by BIOS.

Comment: If the device is not enumerated then it will not have a logical address in the PCI map; without such an address I don't see how a DMA can be set up in the first place.

Comment: @PeterSmith it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, "enumeration" is the process where the BIOS/OS asks all devices what their IDs are. If no driver is found for some device, it still has been enumerated, the OS just does not know what to do with it.

The PCI Express specification says that a device is allowed to issue memory or I/O requests only when the "Bus Master Enable" configuration bit has been set. This bit is usually set by the driver, but your device could simply ignore it (the pcileech device obviously does this).

Memory requests go to a specific address. In many systems, this address is the same as the memory address, but modern systems have an [IOMMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input%E2%80%93output_memory_management_unit) that maps between PCIe bus addresses and memory bus addresses, in order to allow efficient hardware accesses in virtual machines. When the IOMMU is enabled, memory requests have an effect only when they go to a bus address that has been registered by the device driver.